# Update Link Button Not Firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-update

I am working on building a web application. I am running into the issue of the Update link button not firing. I have tested the connection to my database and the insert statement (although the link button is not shown below) works properly on every form I have created. Myself and my coworkers cannot figure out why the Update link button is not updating the database.

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="Program" ContentPlaceHolderId="MainContent">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="ProgramUpdatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:GridView ID="gridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="PRIMARY_KEY_ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" OnRowCancelingEdit="gridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowEditing="gridView1_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="gridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowUpdated="gridView1_RowUpdated">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PRIMARY_KEY_ID" HeaderText="PRIMARY_KEY_ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="PRIMARY_KEY_ID" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PROGRAM" SortExpression="PROGRAM">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtProgram" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PROGRAM") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblProgram" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PROGRAM") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DESC" SortExpression="DESC">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesc" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DESC") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDesc" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DESC") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RANK" SortExpression="RANK">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtRank" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RANK") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblRank" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("RANK") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ACTIVITY" SortExpression="ACTIVITY">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbActivityEdit" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("ACTIVITY") %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="cbActivity" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("ACTIVITY") %>' Enabled="false" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DATE_ORIGIN" SortExpression="DATE_ORIGIN">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateOrigin" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DATE_ORIGIN") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDateOrigin" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DATE_ORIGIN") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DATE_MODIFIED" SortExpression="DATE_MODIFIED">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDateModifiedEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DATE_MODIFIED") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDateModified" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DATE_MODIFIED") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ORIGIN_BY" SortExpression="ORIGIN_BY">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtOriginBy" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ORIGIN_BY") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblOriginBy" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ORIGIN_BY") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MODIFIED_BY" SortExpression="MODIFIED_BY">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblModifiedByEdit" runat="server" Text='<%# Session["CurrentUserName"] %>'></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblModifiedBy" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("MODIFIED_BY") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HISTORY" SortExpression="HISTORY">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHistory" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HISTORY") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblHistory" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HISTORY") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    <div>
    </div>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DB_CONNECTION %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblPRIMARY]"
            InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tblPRIMARY]
            ([PROGRAM],[DESC], [RANK], [ACTIVITY], [DATE_ORIGIN], [DATE_MODIFIED], [ORIGIN_BY], [MODIFIED_BY], [HISTORY])
            VALUES
            (@PROGRAM, @DESC, @RANK, @ACTIVITY, @DATE_ORIGIN, @DATE_MODIFIED, @ORIGIN_BY, @MODIFIED_BY, @HISTORY)"
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tblPRIMARY]
            SET [PROGRAM] = @PROGRAM,
            [DESC] = @DESC,
            [RANK] = @RANK,
            [ACTIVITY] = @ACTIVITY,
            [DATE_ORIGIN] =@DATE_ORIGIN,
            [DATE_MODIFIED] = @DATE_MODIFIED,
            [ORIGIN_BY] = @ORIGIN_BY,
            [MODIFIED_BY] = @MODIFIED_BY,
            [HISTORY] = @HISTORY
            WHERE [PRIMARY_KEY_ID] = @PRIMARY_KEY_ID"
            >
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="PRIMARY_KEY_ID" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="PROGRAM" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DESC" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="RANK" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ACTIVITY" Type="Boolean" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DATE_ORIGIN" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DATE_MODIFIED" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ORIGIN_BY" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="MODIFIED_BY" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="HISTORY" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>

            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="PRIMARY_KEY_ID" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="PROGRAM" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DESC" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="RANK" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ACTIVITY" Type="Boolean" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DATE_ORIGIN" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="DATE_MODIFIED" Type="DateTime" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="ORIGIN_BY" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="MODIFIED_BY" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="HISTORY" Type="String" />
            </UpdateParameters>
             </asp:SqlDataSource>

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </asp:Content>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: There should be a `ScriptManager` control before the `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: @MuhammadAftab I have the ScriptManager control on my Site Master page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Validation controls in your page. Your page must pass the validation before postback to server. Below is the functionality of CausesValidation property:

- The CausesValidation property specifies if a page is validated when a
  Button control is clicked.
- Page validation is performed when a button is clicked by default.
- This property is mostly used to prevent validation when a cancel or reset button is clicked.

Try setting `CausesValidation="False"` in your `Update` button.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. In my code behind I also have a label that outputs "Update complete" that is in my gridView1_RowUpdating event, and that is displaying on the bottom of the web page.